# how to align buttons in linear layout (viewpager dots indicator)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-linearlayout

I want my layout something like this

[image]

for ViewPagerIndicator I have used linear layout and for skip and next used flat buttons.

from my below code I'm getting output as

[image]

I want help over here.

here is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/viewPagerCountDots"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/pager_height"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ll_footer"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFlat
        android:id="@+id/skip"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/viewPagerCountDots"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="Skip"
        />

    <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFlat
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/viewPagerCountDots"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="Next" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try change `<Linearlayout ` to <RelativeLayout

Comment: by changing linear to relative...now displays only one dot

Comment: ok after i'm check your layout,i move my comment to answer,hope this help

Answer (score 0):

after i'm check your layout the problem is on linearLayout
you can try this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/viewPagerCountDots"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFlat
        android:id="@+id/skip"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="Skip"/>
    <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFlat
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="Next" />
</RelativeLayout>
```